# spresenseとLTEボードでNTPで時刻取得すると、希にエラーになる

Tags: spresense

サンプルを参考にNTPで時刻取得すると希にエラーが発生します。

表示されるエラー

```
ERROR:LTEUDP:337 sendoto() error : 22
```

ソースは単純で以下になります。

```
timeClient.begin();
timeClient.update();
now =timeClient.getEpochTime();
tm_now = localtime(&now);
timeClient.end();
```

このエラーが出たとき、再度NTPで時刻を取得するように上記のソースを実行しても
同じエラーが繰り返し出て、いつまでもNTPで時刻がとれません。
エラー出なければ、普通に時刻取得できて問題ありません。
頻度が少ないのでなかなか検証もできない状況です

対処方法をご存じの方、ご教授いただけると助かります。

Comment: `ntp` の接続先はどこになっていますか？まさか福岡大学とか？混雑しすぎていて拒絶されているのかも。お使いの ISP が提供している `ntpd` ないしはネットワーク的に近いところを使うように接続先を確認してください（実験目的なら自分自身に `ntpd` 立てて自分に接続するのが吉）

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 接続先はntp.nict.jpです。サンプル通りと思います。これなら問題ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

> このエラーが出たとき、再度NTPで時刻を取得するように上記のソースを実行しても
> 同じエラーが繰り返し出て、いつまでもNTPで時刻がとれません。

エラーが発生した際、以下のようにNTPを再取得すると正しく時刻が取得できるかもしれません。(一旦 `end`を呼び出したうえで `begin` を呼び出しています。)

```
timeClient.end();
timeClient.begin();
timeClient.update();
now =timeClient.getEpochTime();
tm_now = localtime(&now);
```

もし、これでも取得できない場合はLTEの接続状態を確認してみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。endを実行してからは後ほど試してみます。現状ここでエラーが出てもその後のMQTT通信はできているので、LTEの接続はおそらく問題ないと思います。